# Node.js private chat system algorithm

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, chat, emit

I use `express`, `socket.io`.

I have two user types

1. site visitors (Site users)
2. admins (site admins)

When visitors visit the site, i add user data(browser, location, ip..etc..) to `VisitorObject` and show the `VisitorObject` to admins.

When admins want to send message to a visitor, i should emit function of only user which the admin wants to type.

I don't want to use

```
io.sockets.emit('newMessage', message);
```

I want to use like this

```
io.sockets[id].emit('newMessage', message);
```

EDIT---

i am connection node.js server with

```
    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000', {query: 'id=' + id});
```

This id is not a socket id, it is the user id. I don't want to use socket.id on send message. I want to use user id. Because socket.id always change for the tab of browser.

Comment: do you want to send message to specific socket (by socket id ) ?

Comment: yes i want ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
  // sending to individual socketid (private message)
  socket.to(<socketid>).emit('newMessage', message);
```

or

```
io.to(<socketid>).emit('newMessage', message);
```

https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

if you need to emit by user_id you can do this

```
socket.join(user_id); // when user connected
```

and than

```
io.to(user_id).emit('newMessage', message)
```

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't want to use socket.id. I want to use user id.